# Service returning generic observables of multiple types(potentialy) - can not subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, rxjs

I'm building an app using Angular. I've looked for a solution but I couldn't figure out one.
I've created an abstract service with generic type of T:

```
  export abstract class AbstractService<T>{

      public _url;

     abstract getRequest(): Observable<T> | Observable<T[]>;

     abstract postRequest(val: T| null): Observable<T>;

  }
```

when I try to subscribe to the service, I get a compilation error:

```
this.service.getRequest().subscribe((data)=>{...})
```

I want the component calling the service to behave differently depending on the observable.
I tried typechecking as follow:

```
let observable = this.service.getRequest()
if(typeof(observable) === typeof(Observable<T>)){...}
```

That didn't work either.
Is it even possible to check the type? is there a mechanism to handle this?

Comment: Where have you implemented your abstract service?

Comment: in the app directory. 
I inject it to the component and then populate it by binding through the template.  like this: 

<parent-component>
    <child-component [service]="notAbstractService">
   </child-component>
</parent-component>

Comment: Show `notAbstractService`, is it implement everything well?

Comment: Did you try this: 
````let observable: Observable<T> | Observable<T[]> = this.service.getRequest();````